# Let's learn geometry

Tags: popularity-contest, geometry

Today our lesson is about rectangles and triangles.

you will be given as an input an `n x n` grid that is based on two characters `#` and `*`
you have to classify it into :  triangle or rectangle.
where `#` represents a point and `*` represents a blank space.

## Example input:

```
 #***
 ##**
 ###*
 ####
```

### Output:

```
 triangle
```

### Another example

```
  ##**
  ##**
  ##**
  ##**
```

## Output:

```
  rectangle
```

Rules:

- You should assume that the input is always either a triangle or a rectangle.
- The only two characters you will receive are: `*` and `#`.
- Assume that n < 100.
- Be creative, this is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest) so the most up-voted answer will win.

Comment: is the aspect ratio considered 1? What I mean is, square is n lines by n columns, right?

Comment: @mniip no there could be 2x2 square in an 4x4 grid

Comment: Could it for example also be an inverted square, ie a hole?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson no the square(rectangle) should be filled completely.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all triangles will have exactly one character at their vertex?

Comment: @user80551 yes, or that would make it a trapezoid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TSQL**

Image recognition? Sounds like a job made for SQL :)

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT LEN(data)-LEN(REPLACE(data,'#','')) c FROM test_t
)
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT c)>2                           THEN 'triangle' 
       WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN c=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = MAX(c) THEN 'square'
                                                          ELSE 'rectangle'
       END result
FROM cte;
```

[An SQLfiddle with sample data and test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f49e/1).

Answer (score 3):

### Python

**Creativity**

*Triangle*

```
Forward     Reverse
#***        ####      ####
##**  +     *###  =   ####
###*        **##      ####
####        ***#      ####
```

*Rectangle*

```
Forward  Reverse
##**     ##**     ##**
##**  +  ##**  =  ##**
##**     ##**     ##**
##**     ##**     ##**
```

**Implementation**

```
s=raw_input();print["tri","rect"][all(a!=b for a,b in zip(s,s[::-1])if a!='\n')]+"angle"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python + Sympy

A problem in Geometry should be only solved mathematically

**Creativity**

if s if the number of "#" in the input stream

Triangle: `n**2+n-2s=0` -> n should be an integer

**Implementation**

```
from sympy import *
s,n=2*raw_input().count("#"),Symbol('n');print["rect","tri"][float(solve(n**2+n-s)[0]).is_integer()]+"angle"
```

Answer (score 1):

### C

**Assumption**: the input does not represent a single-line degenerate rectangle, e.g.

```
****
*##*
****
****
```

as arguably this is also a degenerate triangle, and violates "the input is always one of the two cases."

**Logic**: Count the number of points in the first two non-empty lines. If they are the same, it is a rectangle. Otherwise, it is a triangle.

**Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char s[99];
    int cnt1=0, cnt2=0;
    int i;
    while(!cnt1) {
        gets(s);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++) cnt1+=(s[i]=='#');
    };
    gets(s);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++) cnt2+=(s[i]=='#');
    puts(cnt1==cnt2?"rectangle":"triangle");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java

A simple straightforward java implementation. It scans the input looking for some 2x2 square which have `#` in two opposing corners with something not a `#` (presumable a `*`) is some other corner. I.E, it searchs for something that shows that the drawing has a diagonal-lined border.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TrianglesAndRectangles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int r;
        while ((r = System.in.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write(r);
        }
        String[] lines = baos.toString().split("\n");
        System.out.println(hasTriangle(lines) ? "triangle" : "rectangle");
    }

    public static boolean hasTriangle(String[] lines) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].length() - 1; j++) {
                boolean a = lines[i].charAt(j) == '#';
                boolean b = lines[i].charAt(j + 1) == '#';
                boolean c = lines[i + 1].charAt(j) == '#';
                boolean d = lines[i + 1].charAt(j + 1) == '#';
                if ((a && d && (!c || !b)) || (b && c && (!a || !d))) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```